# After creating a link out of a text, take that text with me to the other page

Tags: php, html, css, web

I've got a problem. Im making a list of stuff and everything on the list is a link that should link to the same page. I want to take that links name, text, whatever you want to call it to the next page but don't know how to do that.

Here's an example!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    <td><a href=uppsatserInfo.php>" . $row['name'] . "</a>

}
```

The " $row['name'] " generates all the data from the row "name" in the database. As you can see, im making a link out of everything that is printed out. The link is to the page "uppsatserInfo.php" and I want to take the name of the link with me to that page, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the name of the page as a GET parameter to `uppsatserInfo.php`. Change this:

```
"<td><a href=uppsatserInfo.php>" . $row['name'] . "</a>"
```

to this:

```
"<td><a href='uppsatserInfo.php?name=" . urlencode($row['name']) . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a>"
```

On `uppsatserInfo.php`, the variable

```
$_GET['name']
```

will have the name of the page.

Comment: Great! You gave a really clear answer :) I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just append it to the URL in the querystring:

```
echo "<td><a href='uppsatserInfo.php?name=" . urlencode($row['name']) . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

You get in on uppsatserInfo.php like so:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

You still need too verify it is a valid value on that page as a user can easily alter this data.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! It was really hard to formulate the issue on google